# Why doesn't Input and Form stick to CSS grid template-columns?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

Heya so I've tried making this table and input-form look the same using CSS grid.

Please have a look at my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9j8zcreb/8/

It fixed some problems using `input { width: 100% }` but the form and inputs still operates very differently to how the other grid works. As you can see, they don't look the same and the input-bar has different widths to the table/list, despite using the same (or similar) grid.

Any clues?

I've tried nesting the `form` inside the div with `.wrapper { display: grid }` and I've tried setting the `form` to a css-class instead `<form className="formgrid">` etc but none has made any difference.

Nesting the form inside the css-grid wrapper operated VERY weirdly where I had to set the `grid-column: 1/5` for the whole form but couldn't set the `input`'s individually.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `input` is not a container element, so maybe grid doesn't do the calculations for it. One "hack" would be to add to the grid child input element width: `100%`

```css
.grid1, .grid2 {
  width:250px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.grid1 > input {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
  <input placeholder="1"/>
  <input placeholder="2"/>
</div>

Without 100% for input

<div class="grid2">
  <input placeholder="1"/>
  <input placeholder="2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have solved this by specifying `min-width` attribute in CSS for each respective input tag.

There was also a problem with `input{padding}` that I did not notice, which made the input's bigger and overlapping.

It's still unclear how there would be a way to set the `min-width` to the same as the other divs – perhaps with event listeners and getting the document.element width.